# How to get the latest value emitted by a Kotlin SharedFlow in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm working with Kotlin `SharedFlows` and I'm trying to get only the latest value emitted by the flow. I've tried using the `last()` operator, but it's not working as expected.

**main**

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val eventBus = EventBus()
    launch {
        val latestValue = eventBus.value.lastOrNull()
        if (latestValue != null) {
            println("Latest value: $latestValue")
        }
    }
    launch {
        repeat(5) {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
    }
    launch {
        delay(5.seconds)
        (5..10).forEach {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
    }
}
```

**EventBus**

```
class EventBus {
    private val _value = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    val value: SharedFlow<Int> = _value.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun increment(number: Int) {
        _value.emit(number)
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

I want to capture only the latest value emitted by the observable. For instance, if the observable emits values from 0 to 4, and then pauses for a while, followed by values from 5 to 10, I want to retain only the final value for each interval. For the initial interval (0 to 4), I want to store 4, and for the second interval (5 to 10), I want to store 10. Is this achievable?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

After @Tenfour04 suggestion I tried some code but it doesn't print 2nd interval latest value.

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val eventBus = EventBus()
    launch {
        repeat(5) {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
    }
    launch {
        delay(5.seconds)
        (5..10).forEach {
            delay(100)
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
    }
    launch {
        val latestValue = eventBus.value.replayCache.firstOrNull()
        if (latestValue != null) {
            println("Latest value: $latestValue")
        }
    }
}

class EventBus {
    private val _value = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(replay = 1)
    val value: SharedFlow<Int> = _value.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun increment(number: Int) {
        _value.emit(number)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`last()` works on any flow, and it under the hood collects the entire flow and then outputs the last value collected. Therefore, it is a function that can never return if called on an infinite flow. SharedFlows are always infinite.

To get the most recent value of a SharedFlow, the SharedFlow should have a `replay` of `1` and then you can call `first()` on it to get the most recent value. If there is no replay, the SharedFlow has no record of its most recent value so it is impossible to retrieve it.

But if nothing has posted to the flow yet, you will actually be getting the next value.

StateFlow may be better suited for what you’re trying to do, because it guarantees there is always a current value that you can check instantly using its `value` property.

Comment: Can you please give me example of stateflow?

Comment: still sharedflow is not returning 2nd interval latest value.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you mean by second interval. You’re launching three coroutines in parallel. The second one has a delay before it sends anything to your EventBus. The third one starts checking for the latest value immediately.

Comment: In this scenario, a third coroutine will collect the emitted values from two other coroutines. The first coroutine emits values 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, with the latest value being 4. The second coroutine emits values 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 after a delay of 5 seconds, with the latest value being 10. However, when the third coroutine collects the emitted values, it only receives the values from the first coroutine, even though the second coroutine has already emitted values. Why is this happening?

Comment: You’re launching all three coroutines simultaneously. Third one happens before second because it doesn’t have a delay in it. If you want both of the first two coroutines to finish before the third one starts, wrap the first two together in `coroutineScope { }`.

Comment: So if I want value from second one then I need to add delay in third one as well?

Comment: That would be the hacky way to do it. Trying to time different delays to coordinate something is hacky. The way I said to do it is the straightforward way to do things orderly. The `launch` function starts a coroutine asynchronously to the function that calls it. Wrapping it in `coroutineScope` makes the launched coroutines children of the new scope, and `coroutineScope` doesn’t return until all of its children are complete.